# Most bought item in store SQL

Tags: java, mysql, sql, items

Hi im currently trying to make a school project saving orders from a pizzashop in mySQL. I want to sort those orders to find the most bought pizza and how many of that pizza that has been sold.

My tables look like this..
[Table with the order id, the nr on the pizza sold and how many of that pizza sold on one order](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iVN5W.png)

I tried running something like this..
SELECT nr as mostbought, qty FROM odetails GROUP BY nr ORDER BY SUM(qty) DESC LIMIT 5;

But it doesnt add up the qty, as nr 5 and 1 is bought 6 times and not 3 and 2.. With the query i wrote it seems to output the highest qty of the most bought..

[Table with the nr of the pizza bought most and qty(which i want added together)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/asBIQ.png)

I hope someone can help us, we are kinda stuck here.. Thanks alot :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are just asking it to give you the quantity from that row, not the SUM of the quantities in the group:

```
SELECT nr AS mostbought, SUM(qty) AS qtysum
FROM odetails
GROUP BY nr
ORDER BY qtysum DESC
LIMIT 5;
```

This will sum the quantities within the group, grouped by the unaliased column `nr`, ordered by the sum of quantities, using the alias given for that, `qtysum`. I avoided using the name `qty` again, since you should avoid using columns that exist in your datasource as alias names, it can confuse the database.

I made a quick example of this here, though I don't know what you `nr` column actually is, so I just used letters, it will work just as well with any data type there: [SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/b8f397/2)

Comment: `GROUP BY 1 ORDER BY 2` hope you don't write SQl like that when you have A4 size pages worth of a SQL query.. This is a very error prone query might give invalid data or not work at all when you change the order of the select columns and forgot about that `GROUP BY 1 ORDER BY 2` part.. So handle with care using this..

Comment: @RaymondNijland Fair enough - I removed the column numbers from the clauses and used the alias directly. For something this short it didn't really matter, but best practice should be to be more specific.

Comment: Thanks for the answer with a good explanation for a beginner as me :)

Comment: @RaymondNijland deprication though rarely actually removes functionality, to prevent legacy code that used that functionality from breaking on an update or migration to the new version - There's quite a bit, not just in SQL but all over different languages that was removed from standards but still works.

Comment: *"deprication though rarely actually removes functionality, to prevent legacy code that used that functionality from breaking on an update or migration to the new version"* i agree i also should have said ideally should MySQL not allow that syntax anymore, as it is just error prone to use besides it is *"deprecated"* ..  Well PHP removed bad legacy old `mysql_*` functions from PHP 7 which where long time deprecated so it happens..   But we are moving way offtopic now..

Answer (score 1):

SELECT nr as mostbought, SUM(qty) FROM odetails GROUP BY 1 ORDER BY 2 DESC LIMIT 5;

Comment: `GROUP BY 1 ORDER BY 2` hope you don't write SQl like that when you have A4 size pages worth of a SQL query.. This is a very error prone query might give invalid data or not work at all when you change the order of the select columns and forgot about that `GROUP BY 1 ORDER BY 2` part.. So handle with care using this..

Comment: .. also this answer should have a explainment, pretty sure this answer will be flagged by the system as low quality and might be vote deleted in the future.. ..